# A simple way to verify the existence of a file on the SFTP server in Java

Tags: java, client, sftp, apache-sshd

I am writing an SFTP client using the [Apache Mina SSHD library](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd), specifically `sshd-sftp 2.3.0`. I chose it instead of the [SSHJ library](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj), because it is possible to write a `String` to a remote file directly, and there are also no unnecessary dependencies.

The task: when sending files to the SFTP server to make a backup copy of the previous file, if any.

I studied all the possibilities that the `SftpClient` class provides, and among them I did not find an easy way to search for a file.

- There are `listDir` and `readDir` methods, they return `Iterable <DirEntry>`, but I suspect that with a large number of files they will work slowly.
- We can simply force a file to be renamed using the `rename` method, but in my case there can be many backup files, and we must first find a free file name.

The current solution is to get the state of the file. If there is no such file, then a `SftpException` will be thrown, for example, "SFTP error (SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE): No such file or directory". This message can be analyzed, and if the file is really not found, then just don't throw this exception further. Here is the code:

```java
    private boolean fileExists(SftpClient sftpClient, String remoteDest) throws IOException {
        try {
            return null != sftpClient.stat(remoteDest);
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            if (e.getStatus() != SftpConstants.SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE) {
                LOGGER.error("Error finding file {}", remoteDest);
                throw e;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The main problem is that this solution is ugly.

However, on the Internet I found only similar solutions using libraries [JSch](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp&method=SSH_FX_NO_SUCH_FILE) and [Trilead SSH-2 for Java](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.trilead.ssh2.SFTPv3FileAttributes).

Perhaps there is another, simpler and more competent way to check for a file on an SFTP server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct solution.

SFTP protocol does not have a *"does a file exist"* query/request. The nearest equivalent is actually the ["stat" query/request](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13#section-8.5). So even if your favourite SFTP library had *"does a file exist"* method/API, it would internally do, what your code does.

An equivalent in JSch: [Using JSch, is there a way to tell if a remote file exists without doing an ls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11968878/850848#20121198)